# Rotation of a string operator in a string-net liquid

Tags: quantum-entanglement, topological-order, topological-phase, anyons

I am reading a review article on [topological order](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03911). On page 6 of Ref. [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03911), the author introduces a 360-degree rotation of the string. And, it is said that a straight string state (i.e. an equivalence class of states generated by a straight string) is different from the class generated by a 360-degree rotation. I am having trouble understanding this part. Take the [$Z_2$-toric code](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021) on a square lattice as an example. A 360-degree rotation (taking the clockwise direction instead of counter-clockwise in Ref. [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03911)) may be pictured as fig. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBzMo.png).

[image]

However, I think the two configurations are identical. We can move the bead up through its string. The result is a straight string with a loop on it. We can deform this loop so that only the straight string remains.

Why then the two configurations are different? Could someone tell me where I am mistaken? Thanks!

---

Add:

I think there might be one reason why the two pictures are different because we cannot apply the allowed string-net rules to transform from one to the other ([see this article for the rules for $Z_2$ toric code](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404617)). The string operator, which creates excitations, is an additional structure in the string-net theory. However, I still don't understand why we cannot use rules for string operators to relate configurations?

Comment: I had the same confusion. Then I realized maybe this should be viewed in a 3D way (but I am not sure)---basically, the left one goes down on the torus and the right one goes up on the torus to the back.